# Table getting renamed

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a table in my worksheet and assigning a name which is same as worksheet name. later I am trying to select one column of the table and trying to conditionally format that. But when I see the macro recorded code I a see that name of the table used there is different. Underscores in table names has been changed to double underscore.

Following is the macro recorded code to select the table column named **Users**

```
Range("abc__xyz__0.5s_tbl[[#All],[Users]]").Select
```

But the name of the table I gave was `abc_xyz_0.5s_tbl`.

Why single underscores got replaced by double underscore?

How to fix this because I have many sheet each having a table and I want to refer the table by respective sheet's name.

Comment: Has the actual table name been changed, or is it just the macro recorder messing up?

Comment: some thing weird happening when I query table.Name I see abc_xyz_0.5s_tbl but when I refer column based on this name it fails and if I pass abc__xyz__0.5s_tbl it works. This is how I assign name to my tables. "Create_Table.Name = (ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name & "_tbl")" interestingly the last underscore which I put in table name is not changed.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183657/vba-listobject-inconsistent-naming-rules-when-using-a-macro-puts-underscores-at).  Maybe start your table name with an underscore.

Comment: "Range("_abc__xyz__0.5s_tbl[[#All],[Duty Cycle]]").Select" Nope man didnt work. There are still double underscores in between.

Comment: It seems that Excel is replacing your spaces with a double underscore. If you're systematically creating this, is it important that you know why or more important that you just take it as is and use it to name tables and reference it in the future? Also can you just confirm there is only 1 space between the words in the Workbook name & Sheet name?

Comment: there is only single underscore in worksheet name.